# ¿Cómo agregar código CSS a mi página?

Tags: html, css

Tengo un sitio web la verdad no entiendo mucho de lo que estoy haciendo pero:

Mi código HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Academia Gamer Latina</title>
</head>
<body link="555555" vlink="999999">
    <div id="welcome"><b><font color="red">Atención: Estamos reclutando programadores y editores gráficos</font></b>. <br><br><a href="proy.html"><b>Proyectos</a> ||| <a href="jue.html">Juegos</a> ||| <a href="don.html">Donativos</a> ||| <a href="http://piratepad.net/GAMLAT" target="_blank">Chat</a></b><br><br>Bienvenidos al proyecto Academia Gamer Latina<br><br>   Nosotros buscamos compartir experiencias y conocimientos de gaming en plataformas PC, Android, Linux y iOS<br><br>  Del mismo modo también hemos fundado una cooperativa de programación para editar juegos ya existentes y crear nuevos<br><br>Finalmente, el apoyo económico que provenga de tu difusión a este sitio web, y mediante el donativo de los interesados, será invertido en más apoyo de programadores para la misma cooperativa, tecnologías que puedan resolver mejor nuestra vivencia en el mundo virtual y finalmente, también será utilizado para financiar albergues animales localizados en la ciudad de México [videos acá]</a><br><br>Envíanos tus videos de gaming a whatsapp +5215568542161 o luisfer333@outlook.es muchas gracias por ser parte<br><br><div style="text-align: center;"><iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Gj2dfyfEMRc?rel=0" style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;" width="420"></iframe></div><br /><br><br>Adherentes a la Academia Gamer Latina:<br><br><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/luishs45/videos" target="_blank">ZeroGames</a>&nbsp;|||&nbsp;<a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCvVJmNEA4hO6YFvAIxst5NA/videos" target="_blank">Maxigamer</a> ||| <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/XXLEONYDASXX/videos" target="_blank">xXLEONYDASXx</a> ||| <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/nicobarreraa/videos" target="_blank">Nicobarrera</a> ||| <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMl7zPblHMjSx6iOpMfD65Q/videos" target="_blank">Academia Gamer Latina</a> ||| <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UClrypkYJLFCW1B2d2r_w49g/videos" target="_blank">Family Templarios</a> <br><br> Recomendados no adheridos aún a la Academia Gamer Latina: <br><br> <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/paula30972/videos">¡Hey!</a> ||| <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCILr-2RVL6GCLn5LnQxTlhA/videos" target="_blank"> Astala Vista</a> ||| <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-TXRRAr_FvLLNkz9Ib98ww/videos" target="_blank"> Evil Teemo</a></span> |||<a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbhacmRBTDSzet69u74GzrQ/videos" target="_blank"> Bogi096 </a> ||| </span><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCe50kq56qUsavVz15X7NIFw/videos" target="_blank">tedj11</a> ||| <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6uLxM14_lSA" target="_blank">SuperstarMacAwesomeville</a> ||| <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ybHpwV2EPzo" target="_blank">Hegal</a> ||| <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bj_PxfFgOVk" target="_blank">Luisgameplay</a> ||| Mario Ovalle ||| Broker ||| Zedrus ||| Whiskas ||| Nukes ||| Vegeta ||| Aerobomber ||| zanpakuto ||| kumara ||| pacosmosis ||| jole24 ||| topwar ||| decepticons ||| lux0s ||| allelujah
</body><script  type="text/javascript" src="index.js">
</script>

</html>
```

Esto me implica a que el formato de texto está en `index.js` de la siguiente forma:

```
window.onload=function(){
var $ = function(c){
    if(c.indexOf('.') == 0)
        return document.getElementsByClassName(c.substring(1))[0];
    if(c.indexOf('#') == 0)
        return document.getElementById(c.substring(1));
    return false
}
Element.prototype.html = function(h){
    if(h)
    return this.innerHTML=h;
    return this.innerHTML;

}
 var full = window.location.host;
var parts = full.split('.');
$('#welcome').setAttribute("style", "width:50%;margin:2% auto;text-align:center;font-family:sans-serif;color:#666;background:#eee;padding:20px 100px;box-shadow:0 5px 9px 0 #bbb;border-radius:5px;text-shadow:0 1px 0 #fff");
var ah = '<b><font color="red">Atención: Estamos reclutando programadores y editores gráficos</font></b>. <br><br><a href="proy.html"><b>Proyectos</a> ||| <a href="jue.html">Juegos</a> ||| <a href="don.html">Donativos</a></b><br><br>Bienvenidos al proyecto Academia Gamer Latina<br><br>  Nosotros buscamos compartir experiencias y conocimientos de gaming en plataformas PC, Android, Linux y iOS<br><br>  Del mismo modo también hemos fundado una cooperativa de programación para editar juegos ya existentes y crear nuevos<br><br>Finalmente, el apoyo económico que provenga de tu difusión a este sitio web, y mediante el donativo de los interesados, será invertido en más apoyo de programadores para la misma cooperativa, tecnologías que puedan resolver mejor nuestra vivencia en el mundo virtual y finalmente, también será utilizado para financiar albergues animales localizados en la ciudad de México [videos acá]</a><br><br>Envíanos tus videos de gaming a whatsapp +5215568542161 o luisfer333@outlook.es muchas gracias por ser parte<br><br><div style="text-align: center;"><iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Gj2dfyfEMRc?rel=0" style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;" width="420"></iframe></div><br /><br><br>Adherentes a la Academia Gamer Latina:<br><br><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/luishs45/videos" target="_blank">ZeroGames</a>&nbsp;|||&nbsp;<a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCvVJmNEA4hO6YFvAIxst5NA/videos" target="_blank">Maxigamer</a> ||| <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/XXLEONYDASXX/videos" target="_blank">xXLEONYDASXx</a> ||| <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/nicobarreraa/videos" target="_blank">Nicobarrera</a> ||| <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMl7zPblHMjSx6iOpMfD65Q/videos" target="_blank">Academia Gamer Latina</a> ||| <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UClrypkYJLFCW1B2d2r_w49g/videos" target="_blank">Family Templarios</a> <br><br> Recomendados no adheridos aún a la Academia Gamer Latina: <br><br> <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/paula30972/videos">¡Hey!</a> ||| <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCILr-2RVL6GCLn5LnQxTlhA/videos" target="_blank"> Astala Vista</a> ||| <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-TXRRAr_FvLLNkz9Ib98ww/videos" target="_blank"> Evil Teemo</a></span> |||<a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbhacmRBTDSzet69u74GzrQ/videos" target="_blank"> Bogi096 </a> ||| </span><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCe50kq56qUsavVz15X7NIFw/videos" target="_blank">tedj11</a> ||| <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6uLxM14_lSA" target="_blank">SuperstarMacAwesomeville</a> ||| <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ybHpwV2EPzo" target="_blank">Hegal</a> ||| <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bj_PxfFgOVk" target="_blank">Luisgameplay</a> ||| Mario Ovalle ||| Broker ||| Zedrus ||| Whiskas ||| Nukes ||| Vegeta ||| Aerobomber ||| zanpakuto ||| kumara ||| pacosmosis ||| jole24 ||| topwar ||| decepticons ||| lux0s ||| allelujah';
$('#welcome').html('<h2>'+sub+'</h2>'+ah+'<br><br><i>Gracias por tu visita!</i>');
setTimeout(function(){top.location='index.js';},9999999999999999);
}
```

Yo quisiera agregar el siguiente código:

```
a:hover {
    color:hotpink;
}
```

¿Dónde debo agregar ese formato para que haga un cambio a rosa al poner el mouse sobre el link, sin que se invalide el formato de texto referido en `index.js`?

En cualquier lugar que lo agrego en JavaScript hace parecer como si `index.js` dejara de existir. Y en cualquier lugar que lo agrego en `html` o no hace nada o aparece como texto.

Comment: https://platzi.com/clases/programacion-basica/concepto/fundamentos-de-programacion/html-css-javascript-de-verdad/material/
o arranca por aca
https://platzi.com/clases/programacion-basica/ te va a aclarar bastante el panorama y en pocos minutos, espero te sea util

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Realmente lo que quieres agregar es CSS, lo cual no tiene nada que ver con Javascript(js). El primero simplemente es una hoja de estilos en cascada mientras que el segundo es un lenguaje de programación.

El CSS lo puedes incluir de tres maneras:

- De manera inline, la cual no te recomiendo y que sería agregando el atributo `style=""` al elemento que le quisieras dar estilos.
- En el fichero HTML, incluyéndolo en el head dentro de las etiquetas

  ```
  <style>
     a:hover {
        color:hotpink;
     }
  </style>
  ```
- En un fichero aparte, añadiéndolo dentro de las etiquetas del `head`, con el siguiente enlace:

  ```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tuHojaDeEstilos.css">
  ```

En este último deberías de agregar el código CSS que tienes arriba (sin etiquetas `<style>`).

**POSDATA**: Para tu caso en concreto la primera forma no te valdrá de nada ya que no se puede utilizar un `:hover` con estilos inline. Dentro de las otras dos posibilidades, te recomendaría apartar el CSS en un fichero externo para una mayor legibilidad y mantenimiento.

### El orden SÍ es importante

En el CSS, como su propio nombre indica (Cascading Style Sheets) es importante el orden en el que apliques los estilos, ya que estos se aplican de arriba a abajo (en cascada), prevaleciendo el último en caso de que haya conflicto entre ellos (en caso de que tengan la misma **[especificidad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/122039/qu%C3%A9-es-y-para-que-se-utiliza-la-especificidad-de-css)**).

Esto se suele tener en cuenta cuando definimos nuestros estilos en un sólo fichero de CSS pero es muy común pasarlo por alto cuando utilizamos varios ficheros.

**RECOMENDACIÓN:** Por ello, el orden (de arriba a abajo) al utilizar varios ficheros que te recomiendo es el siguiente:

- En primer lugar deberían ir los ficheros de CSS correspondientes a las librerías.
- En segundo lugar, los ficheros de CSS con tus estilos personalizados.

Te recomiendo este orden porque hay librerías que aplican muchos estilos a elementos comunes de la página (botones, bordes, paddings, etc...) y, en caso de que quieras personalizarlos, si incluyes estas librerías en último lugar, tus estilos serán sobreescritos ya que los de la librería se encontrarán en último lugar.

Por supuesto, esto no implica que no tengas que "jugar" con la especificidad de CSS en algunos casos debido a que las librerías suelen usar una especificidad mayor (incluso hacen uso de `!important` en muchos casos), pero te evitará muchos males de cabeza en otras muchas ocasiones.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Así lo haré!

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Academia Gamer Latina</title>
<style>
   a:hover {
      color:hotpink;
   }
</style>
</head>
<body link="555555" vlink="999999">
    <div id="welcome"><b><font color="red">Atención: Estamos reclutando programadores y editores gráficos</font></b>. <br><br><a href="proy.html"><b>Proyectos</a> ||| <a href="jue.html">Juegos</a> ||| <a href="don.html">Donativos</a> ||| <a href="http://piratepad.net/GAMLAT" target="_blank">Chat</a></b><br><br>Bienvenidos al proyecto Academia Gamer Latina<br><br>   Nosotros buscamos compartir experiencias y conocimientos de gaming en plataformas PC, Android, Linux y iOS<br><br>  Del mismo modo también hemos fundado una cooperativa de programación para editar juegos ya existentes y crear nuevos<br><br>Finalmente, el apoyo económico que provenga de tu difusión a este sitio web, y mediante el donativo de los interesados, será invertido en más apoyo de programadores para la misma cooperativa, tecnologías que puedan resolver mejor nuestra vivencia en el mundo virtual y finalmente, también será utilizado para financiar albergues animales localizados en la ciudad de México [videos acá]</a><br><br>Envíanos tus videos de gaming a whatsapp +5215568542161 o luisfer333@outlook.es muchas gracias por ser parte<br><br><div style="text-align: center;"><iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Gj2dfyfEMRc?rel=0" style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;" width="420"></iframe></div><br /><br><br>Adherentes a la Academia Gamer Latina:<br><br><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/luishs45/videos" target="_blank">ZeroGames</a>&nbsp;|||&nbsp;<a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCvVJmNEA4hO6YFvAIxst5NA/videos" target="_blank">Maxigamer</a> ||| <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/XXLEONYDASXX/videos" target="_blank">xXLEONYDASXx</a> ||| <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/nicobarreraa/videos" target="_blank">Nicobarrera</a> ||| <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMl7zPblHMjSx6iOpMfD65Q/videos" target="_blank">Academia Gamer Latina</a> ||| <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UClrypkYJLFCW1B2d2r_w49g/videos" target="_blank">Family Templarios</a> <br><br> Recomendados no adheridos aún a la Academia Gamer Latina: <br><br> <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/paula30972/videos">¡Hey!</a> ||| <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCILr-2RVL6GCLn5LnQxTlhA/videos" target="_blank"> Astala Vista</a> ||| <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-TXRRAr_FvLLNkz9Ib98ww/videos" target="_blank"> Evil Teemo</a></span> |||<a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbhacmRBTDSzet69u74GzrQ/videos" target="_blank"> Bogi096 </a> ||| </span><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCe50kq56qUsavVz15X7NIFw/videos" target="_blank">tedj11</a> ||| <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6uLxM14_lSA" target="_blank">SuperstarMacAwesomeville</a> ||| <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ybHpwV2EPzo" target="_blank">Hegal</a> ||| <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bj_PxfFgOVk" target="_blank">Luisgameplay</a> ||| Mario Ovalle ||| Broker ||| Zedrus ||| Whiskas ||| Nukes ||| Vegeta ||| Aerobomber ||| zanpakuto ||| kumara ||| pacosmosis ||| jole24 ||| topwar ||| decepticons ||| lux0s ||| allelujah
</body><script  type="text/javascript" src="index.js">
</script>

</html>
```

Ya lo puedes agregar

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Academia Gamer Latina</title>
 <style type="text/css">
   a:hover {
      color:hotpink;
   }
</style>
</head>
<body link="555555" vlink="999999">
    <div id="welcome"><b><font color="red">Atención: Estamos reclutando programadores y editores gráficos</font></b>. <br><br><a href="proy.html"><b>Proyectos</a> ||| <a href="jue.html">Juegos</a> ||| <a href="don.html">Donativos</a> ||| <a href="http://piratepad.net/GAMLAT" target="_blank">Chat</a></b><br><br>Bienvenidos al proyecto Academia Gamer Latina<br><br>   Nosotros buscamos compartir experiencias y conocimientos de gaming en plataformas PC, Android, Linux y iOS<br><br>  Del mismo modo también hemos fundado una cooperativa de programación para editar juegos ya existentes y crear nuevos<br><br>Finalmente, el apoyo económico que provenga de tu difusión a este sitio web, y mediante el donativo de los interesados, será invertido en más apoyo de programadores para la misma cooperativa, tecnologías que puedan resolver mejor nuestra vivencia en el mundo virtual y finalmente, también será utilizado para financiar albergues animales localizados en la ciudad de México [videos acá]</a><br><br>Envíanos tus videos de gaming a whatsapp +5215568542161 o luisfer333@outlook.es muchas gracias por ser parte<br><br><div style="text-align: center;"><iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Gj2dfyfEMRc?rel=0" style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;" width="420"></iframe></div><br /><br><br>Adherentes a la Academia Gamer Latina:<br><br><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/luishs45/videos" target="_blank">ZeroGames</a>&nbsp;|||&nbsp;<a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCvVJmNEA4hO6YFvAIxst5NA/videos" target="_blank">Maxigamer</a> ||| <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/XXLEONYDASXX/videos" target="_blank">xXLEONYDASXx</a> ||| <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/nicobarreraa/videos" target="_blank">Nicobarrera</a> ||| <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMl7zPblHMjSx6iOpMfD65Q/videos" target="_blank">Academia Gamer Latina</a> ||| <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UClrypkYJLFCW1B2d2r_w49g/videos" target="_blank">Family Templarios</a> <br><br> Recomendados no adheridos aún a la Academia Gamer Latina: <br><br> <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/paula30972/videos">¡Hey!</a> ||| <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCILr-2RVL6GCLn5LnQxTlhA/videos" target="_blank"> Astala Vista</a> ||| <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-TXRRAr_FvLLNkz9Ib98ww/videos" target="_blank"> Evil Teemo</a></span> |||<a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbhacmRBTDSzet69u74GzrQ/videos" target="_blank"> Bogi096 </a> ||| </span><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCe50kq56qUsavVz15X7NIFw/videos" target="_blank">tedj11</a> ||| <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6uLxM14_lSA" target="_blank">SuperstarMacAwesomeville</a> ||| <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ybHpwV2EPzo" target="_blank">Hegal</a> ||| <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bj_PxfFgOVk" target="_blank">Luisgameplay</a> ||| Mario Ovalle ||| Broker ||| Zedrus ||| Whiskas ||| Nukes ||| Vegeta ||| Aerobomber ||| zanpakuto ||| kumara ||| pacosmosis ||| jole24 ||| topwar ||| decepticons ||| lux0s ||| allelujah
</body><script  type="text/javascript" src="index.js">
</script>

</html>
```

Asi lo puedes lograr

Answer (score 0):

Hola Amigo espero que en te pueda ayudar veraz en la imagen una parte recuadrada ai agregas a tu código html un hoja de estilo css, en donde esta HREF"" ai entre las comillas pones el nombre de el archivo.
[image: Hola Amigo espero que en te pueda ayudar veraz en la imagen una parte recuadrada ai agregas a tu código html un hoja de estilo css, en donde esta HREF"" ai entre las comillas pones el nombre de el archivo.]