# Animación en Borde hecho en CSS

Tags: html, css

Estoy usando un código de Codepen para crear una animación en Loop al borde de un texto, todo está hecho en CSS, pero cuando lo trato de hacer en mi computadora, no funciona, también lo he probado en mi página y nada, alguien me puede ayudar a ver porque no me sale cuando lo pruebo?

Este es el código: https://codepen.io/jvera/pen/gXxgXx

Yo he creado los 2 archivos (html y CSS) y los he puesto en una carpeta, cuando abro el html, no me sale nada, sale todo en blanco (ni el título en html).

Quizás sea la extensión? al estilo le he puesto .css pero en la descripción del código dice que es SASS y nose si usa otro tipo de extensión?

Gracias.

**Actualización:** Ya me aparece el texto, pero sin el efecto.

```css
{
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #f45e61;
  color: #f45e61;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.draw {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.draw::before, .draw::after {
  content: '';
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.draw::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top-color: #60daaa;
  border-right-color: #60daaa;
  animation: border 2s infinite;
}
.draw::after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  animation: border 2s 1s infinite, borderColor 2s 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes border {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  25% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
@keyframes borderColor {
  0% {
    border-bottom-color: #60daaa;
    border-left-color: #60daaa;
  }
  50% {
    border-bottom-color: #60daaa;
    border-left-color: #60daaa;
  }
  51% {
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<center><h2 class="draw">Titulo</h2><center>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. This is the Spanish version of StackOverflow, so, please translate your question to get answers. Second, the first CSS block is not applied to any element. Fix that and your code should works as expected.

Comment: Hola, como edito mi pregunta? no encuentro la opción para editar mi pregunta y ponerla en Español.

Comment: Debajo de las etiquetas de la pregunta puedes encontrar la palabrra editar, que te permite editar cambios. Justo debajo del botón de ejecutar el script de la pregunta

Comment: Listo, ya lo hice en español, por favor, si lo pueden publicar. Gracias

Comment: pero si funciona, se ve igual al link que envias

Comment: estoy leyendo más sobre SASS y veo que debo tenerlo instalado, yo pensaba que era como CSS, pero bueno, ya lo instalé en mi Mac, pero aún no lo veo, también veo que debo de compilarlo. 

Ojjo @renelimon en el link si sale, porque me imagino que tienen SASS instalado, pero en local como lo hago?

Comment: no hace falta sass para esto, es css puro, no sé si estes probando en distintos navegadores

Comment: Lo he probado en Firefox y Chrome y en ninguno anda.

Comment: @Kenyis ¿Cómo estás importando tu CSS? Puedes consultar como poder agregar el código CSS [en esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/76412/c%C3%B3mo-agregar-c%C3%B3digo-css-a-mi-p%C3%A1gina/76415#76415)

Comment: Hola, ya lo solucioné, me faltaron 2 cosas, jalar el archivo css desde el header y 2 descagar el SASS compilado en CSS.

Comment: Ya has solucionado tu problema @Kenyis? Si es así, pon lo que hiciste como respuesta para que la gente sepa que ya está solucionado. Saludos