# Angular - Diferentes hojas de estilo CSS para un mismo componente

Tags: html, css, angular

Tengo una sección que se repite en varios componentes y los estilos CSS son iguales para todas ellas. Para dejar el código más limpio, he quitado los estilos repetidos de cada una de las hojas de estilos CSS de los componentes y lo he puesto todo en la hoja de estilos del componente padre. No obstante, cuando lo hago no me los reconoce... ¿Será que he olvidado enlazar algún fichero? Soy nuevo en Angular.

Por ejemplo, tengo los siguientes componentes:

```
<app-root>
    <componente-hijo1>...</componente-hijo1>
    <componente-hijo2>...</componente-hijo2>
    <componente-hijo3>...</componente-hijo3>
</app-root>
```

En cada componente hijo tengo, por ejemplo, la clase ".prueba" con una serie de atributos CSS asociados.

```
.prueba {
    background-color: red;
    color: blue;
    ...
}
```

Lo que quiero es no repetir código y en lugar de tener esa clase en cada hoja de estilos de los componentes hijos, tenerla una sola vez en la del padre. ¿Es eso posible?

Comment: Desgraciadamente no somos adivinos por lo que si no muestros tus estilos o das una descripcion mas detallada de tu problema no podremos ayudarte

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo agregar código CSS a mi página?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/76412/c%c3%b3mo-agregar-c%c3%b3digo-css-a-mi-p%c3%a1gina)

Comment: Lo he actualizado para explicarme mejor :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Respondiendo a tu pregunta**, puedes utilizar un mismo archivo de estilos para varios componentes. 
Esto que planteas se suele utilizar para definir paleta de colores, clases genéricas, animaciones y/o `@keyframes`.

### Ejemplos:

Puedes hacerlo de diferentes formas, una seria la siguiente:

**component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
```

Como se puede ver importas un .scss a tu componente, el cual tiene en su interior uno o varios, `@import` de otras hojas de estilo.

**component.scss**

```
@import '../assets/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css';
@import '../assets/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css';
@import '../assets/plugins/ionRangeSlider/css/ion.rangeSlider.css';
@import '../assets/plugins/ionRangeSlider/css/ion.rangeSlider.skinNice.css';
```

Como puedes ver hago import de varias hojas de estilo diferentes, a modo de ejemplo, aquí tu deberéis importar tu hoja de estilo genérica para dicho componente.

**Otra posible solución** es la siguiente, importar varias hojas de css, directamente en el `component.ts`

```
  @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls:  ['style1.css', 'style2.css']
    })
```

Yo recomendaría menos esta ultima forma, ya que puede resultar más claro hacer `@import` dentro del `.sccs` y es lo que se suele recomendar para heredar paleta de colores, etc.

Comment: Como actualización a esta buena respuesta, recomiendo hoy día usar `@use` en lugar de `@import`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62757419/whats-the-difference-between-import-and-use-scss-rules

Answer (score 0):

Sí, el mejor caso sería crear un fichero CSS dónde quieras y en vez de utilizar ninguno o el de cada componente para tus componentes hijos utilizar ese fichero simplemente apuntando a la ruta de este nuevo fichero en cada componente hijo. Recuerda, que un componente puede tener todos los ficheros CSS/SCSS qué quieras.

La **herencia** en Angular es posible, pero normalmente se utiliza la **inyección de dependencias** ya qué está más adaptado a la arquitectura de Angular.