# Justify-content: right no ubica el elemento a la derecha

Tags: css

No sé si estoy complicándome la vida. Lo único que quiero es que la parte donde aparece el porcentaje con color de fondo, aparezca alineado a la derecha, al igual que los números de arriba. Estoy usando `display:flex` y `justify-content:right`, que entiendo que debería desplazarme todo el contenido a la derecha, pero no es así.

```html
<div style="max-width:20%;display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;">
  <p class="old-price" style="width:100%;text-decoration: line-through;text-align:right;">19.99€</p>
  <p class="current-price" style="width:100%;font-size:18px;text-align:right;margin-top:4px;">24.99€</p>
    <div style="display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;justify-content:right;width:100%;">
      <div style="background:#ff5454;display:flex;padding:3px;margin-top:4px;width:55px;justify-content: right;" class="current-discount">
        <p style="margin:auto;color:white;font-weight:500;">+21%</p>
      </div>
    </div>                                               
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplemente añádele un `margin-left: auto` al `div` que contiene el número con tu porcentaje.

Por otro lado, no es necesario que englobes dicho `div` dentro de otro, podrías alinear directamente el `div` que contiene el texto, por lo que podrías eliminar el que contiene a ese `div`.

Para alinear el texto dentro de tu `div` a la derecha simplemente añade `text-align: right`.

Tu ejemplo modificado:

```html
<div style="max-width:20%;display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;">
  <p class="old-price" style="width:100%;text-decoration: line-through;text-align:right;">19.99€</p>
  <p class="current-price" style="width:100%;font-size:18px;text-align:right;margin-top:4px;">24.99€</p>
      <div style="background:#ff5454;text-align:right;padding:3px;margin-top:4px;width:55px; margin-left: auto;" class="current-discount">
        <p style="margin:auto;color:white;font-weight:500;">+21%</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**IMPORTANTE**: Te recomiendo que no utilices nunca o en la medida de lo posible estilos inline, es decir, que se encuentren en el propio elemento con el atributo `style`. En su defecto, utiliza ID's o clases en un fichero externo.

Puedes consultar esta pregunta para más información: [¿Cómo agregar código CSS a mi página?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/76412/c%C3%B3mo-agregar-c%C3%B3digo-css-a-mi-p%C3%A1gina/76415#76415)

También puedes consultar esta auto pregunta-respuesta mía hablando sobre porque no hay que utilizar estilos inline: [¿Qué es y para que se utiliza la especificidad de CSS?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/122039/qu%C3%A9-es-y-para-que-se-utiliza-la-especificidad-de-css)

Comment: ¡Gracias! Me ha servido.

Answer (score 1):

No necesitas el `display: flex; justify-content: right` en el segundo `div`, con ponerle `text-align:right` quedará alineado a la derecha

```html
<div style="max-width:20%;display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;">
  <p class="old-price" style="width:100%;text-decoration: line-through;text-align:right;">19.99€</p>
  <p class="current-price" style="width:100%;font-size:18px;text-align:right;margin-top:4px;">24.99€</p>
  <div style="display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;justify-content:right;width:100%;">
    <div style="background:#ff5454;padding:3px 0 3px 3px;margin-top:4px;width:55px;text-align: right;" class="current-discount">
      <p style="margin:auto;color:white;font-weight:500;">+21%</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```